# Disable "Tip for your Google Chrome"

Tags: google-chrome, avast

Avast has added something to their software which Google Chrome tip whenever it informs you of an database update:

[image: Avast Virus Definition Update Message]

It seems to only be the same message at the moment, as I am only getting the

> Search with Google right from the address bar to save time.  Try Now:

**How can I stop it from giving me this tip and only show me the virus definitions have been updated message?**

> Your virus definitions have been automatically updated

---

I have tried looking under `Settings > Popups`, however I cannot find an option to disable it there. I tried these settings that is in my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/484232/86550)

In the avast! settings interface there is an option to turn off recommendations and tips:

> Settings > Community

**Edit**: It doesn't seem to work anymore, it worked for the next 2 database updates and now it is showing the tip again.

**EDIT2**: Working again.  I think I may just have experienced a bug.

Comment: I think this setting may be a solution, however I will need to wait until the next definition update to test it: [Show avast! recommendation features](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G3m9x.png)

Comment: You can try `Right click -> Show last popup message` in the tray.

Comment: Yes! That worked.  Writing answer now.

Comment: @njallam: You forgot to also mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: You have to wait 48 hours before marking your own answer as the accepted answer.  I will when I can :)

Comment: OK, correction: It doesn't seem to work anymore, it worked for the next 2 database updates and now it is showing the tip again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the avast! settings interface there is an option to turn off recommendations and tips:

```
Settings > Community
```

[image: Show avast! recommendation features]